How to test an Angular Component with TranslateTestingModule.withTranslations() using MockBuilder (from ng-mocks)
i am using ng-mocks and want to test an angular component which uses translations.
i would love to use the .withTranslation to respect the language file structure.
but yet i've not found a way to use the TranslateTestingModule and need to mock the TranslateService instead like:
  beforeEach(() =>
      MockBuilder(MyDialogComponent)
        .mock(TranslateService, { instant: (key) =>
            key.includes('rejected') ? 'No!': 'OK!'
        })
        .provide(MyDialogService)
        .then(() => service = TestBed.inject(MyDialogService))
  );

has anybody an idea how to get it?
I've tried to use the mock builder instead like:
const ngModule = MockBuilder(BonusDialogComponent)
      .provide(BonusDialogService)
      .build();

    ngModule.imports = [TranslateTestingModule.withTranslations(LANGUAGE, TRANSLATIONS)];
    service = TestBed.inject(BonusDialogService);
    return TestBed.configureTestingModule(ngModule).compileComponents();

but only got an No Provider for TranslateService

i guess you can .mock(TranslateTestingModule.withTranslations(LANGUAGE, TRANSLATIONS))

thank you!
i found an other suitable solution:
  beforeEach(() => MockBuilder([
    MyDialogComponent,
    TranslateModule,
    TranslateTestingModule.withTranslations('de', de),
  ])
    .provide(BonusDialogService)
    .then(() => service = TestBed.inject(MyDialogService))
  );

its the same with routes:
https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/guides/route
